# How to receive URL parameters with codeigniter

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, codeigniter, get

I am trying to send parameters to a `GET` method using `codeigniter` and `angularJS` but it seems my function doesn't receive the parameter. Here is the code:

**AngularJS:**

```
$http.get("../controller/get_method?id=13").then(function(response) {
    $scope.data= response.data;
    //console.log(response.data);
}, function myError(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**CodeIgniter:**

```
public function get_method()
{
    header ( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' );
    $id= isset ($_GET ['id']) ? $_GET ['id'] : null;

    $sql = "select * from table";

    if ($id) $sql." where table.id=".$id;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    echo json_encode( $query->result_array() );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming you've routed `get_method` too `get_boxes`, codeigniter _basically_ access get parameters as `/` (dash) and they are passed as function arguments. I suggest you consult the documentation. (Edit: You didn't mention altering the config for query string.)

Comment: Sidenote: codeigniter has a class to retrieve 'form' data, aka [Input Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html).

Comment: @FirstOne, actually it is `get_method`(I have updated it on the post). I have tryied `uri_to_assoc` method from the documentation too and didn't work. What you mean by query string config?

Comment: I'd suggest you to just use the regular codeigniter way of GET (learn how it's done and how codeigniter does it - it's automatic as it passes the value to the controller's function as argument). Anyways, you can look into [Enabling Query Strings](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#enabling-query-strings) - which for me, is not worth it, in your case.

Comment: @FirstOne yes, I can't enable query strings on my project actually. I am following what the documentation says but it just seems not to work. I can acess my function correctly but no parameters are received.

Comment: This is dragging too long. The documentation is there, read it. You said no parameters are received, but in the question your function is defined as `get_method()`, **YOU** didn't define the parameters. Read this section: [**Passing URI Segments to your methods**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods). See how the defined function takes two parameters to be 'injected' by CI when you access that url with two more data? (controller/method/data1/data2)

Comment: I have tried both approachs of using `URI segments` (defining the variables on the function or by using association) and none of that worked for me. Believe me, I wouldn't ask this here if I hadn't tried the methos on the documentation before.

Comment: You didn't mention it in the question, though right? If this doesn't work, then I don't really know. Try this just for the sake of it, changing the url to `.../get_method/13` and the function to `function get_method($foo){echo $foo;}`. Again, if it doesn't work, I don't know.

Comment: I haven't mentioned that, I am sorry. And this didn't work too. The url is correct. Thank you for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are two (well 3 if you are doing things your way) ways of getting data in Codeigniter controller function.

First:

```
function some_controller_function($id = null) { var_dump($id) }
```

Second - only works for non routed methods unless handled properly:

```
function some_controller_function() {
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    if (is_null($id)) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Further, please please please *don't* directly input your raw `$_GET` data directly in to your query string. This just opens you up to SQL injection. Use query-builder which automatically escapes data. Or do it manually via `$id = $this->db->escape_str($this->input->get('id'));`

Query builder code:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('id' => $id);
return $query->result_array();
```

If *none* of the aforementioned functions work then you must be doing something else wrong outside the scope of the information you posted. Go through the typical debug routes.

Comment: The first method worked for me. Thank you for your answer. My problem was on the parameters of my URL.